# Where to set DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS?

Tags: python, django

I need to change used database configuration on application execute depending on environment. I have following configuration for db:

```
DATABASES = {
    'localhost': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_VAR, 'data/localhost.sqlite3'),
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'novumaz',
        'USER': 'novumaz',
        'PASSWORD': 'novumaz',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'production': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'set database name',
        'USER': 'set database user name',
        'PASSWORD': 'set database user password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Tried set it in wsgi.py and manage.py. Non of them works.

Comment: Instead of change database configuration based on environment,I think better to use multiple settings file more details http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/projects.html#settings

Answer (score 0):

This should go in your projects 'settings.py' file -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

Answer (score 0):

Quote from this ticket:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16989

"I'm not sure what gave you the idea that DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS is a setting, but it isn't. DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS is a constant, defined in the django.db module, that expands to "default"."

According to django's documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

"The DATABASES setting must configure a default database; any number of additional databases may also be specified."

Your configuration example does not have any database named 'default'.